# Google reCaptcha certificate error in sharepoint 2013 visual webpart

Tags: 2013, web-part

I've following code to verify Google reCaptcha. This code work without any problem on a regular .NET project (http/https) doesn't matter works fine on both protocols.

But when it comes to a Sharepoint 2013 Visual Webpart `UploadValues` line gives this error. Tested sites are http and https gives error on both.

`The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`

I tried to put a dummy https url instead of siteverify url and it passes `UploadValues` line without giving error.

What might be the problem with reCaptcha and Sharepoint Visual Webpart?

FYI: Server has a valid wildcard SSL Certificate which sharepoint sites run with no problem.

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
    {
        var data = new NameValueCollection();
        data["secret"] = "MY_SECRET_KEY";
        data["response"] = Page.Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
        byte[] response = wb.UploadValues("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", "POST", data);
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response));
        Literal1.Text = json.GetValue("success").ToString();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. save google's root certificate from link https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/
2. add this cert on Central Administration =>Security =>Manage Trust

Comment: Thanks for reply, unfortunately it didn't work. I also tried the certificate from https://pki.google.com but that didn't work too :(

Comment: Does it call "Google Trust Services - GlobalSign Root CA-R2"?

Comment: it says `Certificate Issuer:  
 
  CN=Google Internet Authority G3, O=Google Trust Services, C=US  
 
Certificate Issued To:  
 
  CN=www.google.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, S=California, C=US`

Comment: It's a site certificate. Go to "Certification Path" tab and take the root cert in tree.

Comment: ah I see, there are two certificates in the path. I was exporting root but when i export the one says google it worked. thanks a lot.